# Difference between US English QWERTY and International English QWERTY Apple keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, internationalization

What exactly is the difference between US English QWERTY and International English QWERTY Apple keyboards?

I'm talking about the hardware keyboards specifically, **not** about keyboard layouts (in System Settings).

Answer (score 143):

The most important differences are the size and position of the Enter/Return, and a few differences in the layout. The `~` key and the `\` key have an entirely different position on both keyboards. Also, the US keyboard has no `€` label (although it can be entered: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>).

The International keyboard (‘keyboard type’ = ISO) also has one more key than the US keyboard (‘keyboard type’ = ANSI).  Some Apple keyboard layouts use that key for essential characters, and this can cause problems for users with only the US keyboard.

Below is a high-quality visual comparison.

### [US QWERTY Apple keyboard](https://web.archive.org/web/20220802120259/https://www.apple.com/ie/shop/product/MK293LB/A/magic-keyboard-with-touch-id-for-mac-models-with-apple-silicon-us-english?fnode=fc3423f5c4d80aa230db8f14c1257b7996634b30a39222ef2fbba247c4ad009befca528146a24dca7a9943bb7776b51458e4e9d8fa66c35faf68852215ebe28ac698e6448e05e1cd283ed4fded748feff23e948a0b59420cdf96563f6e423ab3):

[image: US keyboard]

### [EN International Apple keyboard](https://web.archive.org/web/20220802120234/https://www.apple.com/ie/shop/product/MK293Z/A/magic-keyboard-with-touch-id-for-mac-models-with-apple-silicon-international-english?fnode=52d28e92ad0f5bf9d2b7d18fedd290be3580762bcb3eef799f8342852d07eb7ceb8a13a720cb71a6110ff9cdbd3df799b65e313d39654eb60dba8489571e0c1f3a170f8db3c9184856069d2a342d72c3b07967403360fb16cfe460452c5624bc):

[image: International keyboard]

Comment: "...the US keyboard has no € label" - this seems to imply that the international English keyboard has a key with a € label but that's not the case - if the attached images are correct.

Comment: Sneaky that the hardware US Qwerty layout from Apple is named English US International on Linux's software mapping... But eh, we have a clear answer on the regular non-L-shaped return key thanks to this, the idea of looking for the [keyboard updating live on their website](https://www.apple.com/nl/search/Magic-Keyboard-US-English) is also a very good approach indeed!

Answer (score 4):

Latest version from the official Apple website:

QWERTY - International & QWERTY - US

[image]

The link below is to the overview of all keyboard layouts that Apple provides. Might be useful.

Link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

Comment: The image is incorrectly labelled. The English keyboard has the large Enter key.

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't have the alternate "upper" characters of the number keys, i.e. the pound sign.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about.  US qwerty and En International have the pound sign £ in exactly the same place, alt plus 3.  Neither of them have it printed on the key.