# How to use plain text smileys (disable automatic emoji substitution) in Messages.app?

Tags: messages, preferences, macos, emoji

How to use plain text smileys (disable automatic emoji substitution) in Messages.app? In OS X 10.8 there was a setting for this in the app’s Preferences pane, but in OS X 10.9 that doesn’t seem to be the case anymore.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not cool to ask and answer your [own questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/difference-between-us-qwerty-and-international-qwerty-apple-keyboards) as a way of posting a tip that you have found, but maybe others disagree...

Comment: @beroe Well, Jeff Atwood disagrees with you. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to ponder that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @beroe Also, http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: But someone else just might come up with an even better answer, as happened here.

Comment: @DanielLawson [Depends on your definition of “better”](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106254/4408#comment127351_106254), but yeah :) Love when this happens.

Comment: @MathiasBynens You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to the Edit menu, submenu Substitutions, then uncheck Emoji.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't quite work anymore for Big Sur, but I think I got it to stop replacements by toggling each of the items./ (They were all already off, but setting them on/off seems to have disabled auto-emoticons, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Run the following command ([source](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/commit/f10eb803cf9cb9ed321bc60e92f662353400a38c)) in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.messageshelper.MessageController SOInputLineSettings -dict-add "automaticEmojiSubstitutionEnablediMessage" -bool false
```

Then restart Messages.app.

Comment: Nice! I always prefer `dwrites` because I keep a file of them that I use to setup a new system the way I like it, rather than checking 100 different menu items. Verified on 10.9.

Comment: Yeah, [me too](http://mths.be/osx). But I guess most people prefer a UI for everything, so I ended up accepting the other answer ;)