# Typing option+s results in surprise emoji () instead of eszett (ß)

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, emoji

Up until a few days ago typing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> resulted in the German eszett (ß). Currently typing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> results in the insertion of the surprise emoji (). If I bring up the Keyboard Viewer and press the <kbd>option</kbd> key by itself, I can see that in theory at least typing `s` should insert ß as I would expect. Clicking on the ß character in the Keyboard Viewer also inserts a .

I have tried

- a different keyboard layout which provides <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as ß: surprise emoji
- activating the standard German keyboard and pressing the key to the left of `0` (zero): ß
- disabling Karabiner, although nothing in the settings suggests such a substitution to be active: surprise emoji

[As indicated in an older question, the emoji substitution check](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108638/5472) doesn’t work on Big Sur.

Do you have any idea how I can debug what is causing this? I cannot recall installing anything recently which might be causing such a change.

Comment: Does this topic answer your question ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106253/how-to-use-plain-text-smileys-disable-automatic-emoji-substitution-in-messages#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Edit%20menu%2C%20submenu%20Substitutions%2C%20then%20uncheck%20Emoji.

Comment: @tama I’ve edited this so it’s clear the selected answer has someone that says it doesn’t work. We should get confirmation from the OP soon if that edit is correct or this can be closed against one of the other answers here / there. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Have you checked system preferences > keyboard > text > replace with for an entry that might do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully found out where the replacement was coming from - it turns out there was an entry in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` which mapped `option`+`s` to the surprise emoji. I had forgotten putting the entry in there.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to share how you fixed your issue. Could you mark your answer as accepted? This shows other people that your question has the answer you were looking for, and will help others that have a similar issue.