# Allow different keys remaps for different keyboards

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I'm using a MBP with a German keyboard. However, as you probably know, it is an annoying layout. Therefore, I use the normal US layout instead. This, however, was not enough. The upper left key (right below the `ESC`) originally maps to `§` and `±`. Therefore, using `karabiner` I remapped it and checked `Swap tilde with section`. This now works as I want on the internal keyboard.

The problem is that when I attach an external native US apple keyboard, the upper left key is mapped to `§` and `±`. Is there a way to disable `karabiner` on the external keyboard? Any other idea?

Comment: You have an ISO keyboard, but you are mapping to an ANSI layout. Would it not be simpler to map it to another ISO layout, like UK English? see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106059/85275

Comment: How does it solve my problem?

Comment: It keeps the key below Escape & the key left of z in their original places - they move on an ANSI keyboard. That way, the Mac itself would be capable of remapping as it recognises a true ANSI keyboard being connected

Comment: After the remaps I have no issue with the internal keyboard. The problem arises when I plug the external one.

Comment: You could try it & see if it works...

Comment: I tried but the problem remains. I guess that the problem is that the two keyboards are different.

Comment: try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/200389/85275