# Wrong keycode on macOS. How to fix?

Tags: keyboard, macos

For some strange reason when I try to type these keys:

1. Grave =  `  = keycode 50
2. Or shift + Grave = tilde = ~ = *I don't know the keycode*

I get different chars, for the grave I get this = §
and for the tilde I get this: ±

My keyboard is:

[image]

My PC is configured right as you can see in the image of the virtual kb:

[image]

I don't have a clue why! Someone how to solve this ?

Comment: What Keyboard are you using? US? Spanish? Portuguese? Italian? French? In macOS Sierra, if you hold down a vowel or consonant key, a small pop-up window appears with all the available diacritical and other marks available. A number appears above the selections, and typing that number inserts that character with the diacritical mark.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/difference-between-us-qwerty-and-international-qwerty-apple-keyboards

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your machine thinks you have an ISO keyboard (which has an extra key to the left of z for grave/tilde) instead of ANSI. Some possible fixes are at

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Answer (score 2):

I just could resolve it using a third app: [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/usage/README.md)

You need to download [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/latest/karabiner-elements-latest.dmg), this version supports the Sierra, if you go to the website, the Karabiner software doesn't.

After installing it, you need to look in the readme for this section:

> Change section key § with accent key `

Apply the configuration and everything will work again!