# How to fix wrong mapping for keyboard on Macbook Pro (correct layout selected)

Tags: macos, keyboard

Mac OS version Big Sur

Even though my keyboard is a niche model (ergonomic, from X-bows), I verified the layout here [Difference between US QWERTY and International QWERTY Apple keyboards?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/difference-between-us-qwerty-and-international-qwerty-apple-keyboards) I have therefore a US (not US international) and should be of of ANSI type.

The following is what makes tricky to understand the exact problem:

- Restarting the macbook and even re-adding the keyboard languages one by one did not help.
- Mac keyboard set up assistant cannot detect the keyboard
- Most keys (including SOME symbols and action keys) work just fine... except instead of some letters (u i o p j k n etc) numbers are typed...
- The exact same external keyboard worked perfectly a week ago. The only thing I did was to use the mac with a different keyboard (I already put back the right keyboard language)

Comment: Link goes to an error in what may be Korean

Comment: Link was a typo, but I've also redirected it to the origin site, which is right here on Stack Exchange, not the copy

Comment: Is this wired/wireless, have you tested it on another computer? Do you have a link to the actual keyboard site? It sounds like a hardware error to me - keys in specific diagonal lines not working hints at PCB damage.

Comment: Those keys typing numbers would seem to indicate that some sort of Numlock is active.  https://www.samsung.com/za/support/computing/when-i-press-the-u-i-o-j-k-l-keys-on-keyboard-numbers-appears-instead/     https://www.macworld.com/article/232180/you-mac-wont-type-u-i-o-j-k-l-and-m-heres-why.html

Comment: Try hitting the option key 5 times or F6 or Fn

Comment: https://x-bows.com/collections/keyboards/products/x-bows-knight-plus-ergonomic-mechanical-keyboard-with-magnetic-number-pad this is the keyboard . wired.

Hitting option-f6-fn multiple times seem to do nothing.

I tested it on a Windows laptop and the same keys also have issues, except they just don't type anything in this case.

I can understand a hardware issue but last time I used it I had 0 issues... and now half of the keys are broken :/

Comment: Have you contacted the people who make it?

Comment: @TomGewecke yeah I did. we'll see how it goes, I'll try to post an update

Comment: You may want to try [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) to fix any keyboard issues.

Comment: In the end using the proprietary software to restore the keyboard factory settings fixed the issue, on all devices / OS involved